# How to check if a particular class in collections (functools, etc) is implemented in C?

Tags: python

I know that many parts of stdlib are implemented in C, e.g. [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Is there a quick way to check if a particular class in `collections` (`functools`, etc) is implemented in C? I would expect such implementations to be faster than pure Python.

Comment: Are you sure `collections.OrderedDict` is implemented in C? I found it's definition `class OrderedDict(dict):` in `/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py`

Comment: It's a bit tricky. For example `functools.lru_cache` appears to be written in Python at first, but if you look closer it mostly uses `_lru_cache_wrapper` which is written in C.

Comment: @Sanya yes, since [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#collections).

Answer (score 0):

In the Python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html for functools) you can click the link besides "Source Code" (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/functools.py for functools) and track whatever you want down from there. It's all on the git